# How to set a variable if set /a fails?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, if-statement

I would like to check if my set /a statement failed with a `Missing operator.` error or not. My current batch file, only sets the variable.
This batch file was meant to test my theory of checking if my set /a statement failed with a `Missing operator.` error or not.

```
@echo off & @setlocal
set "rndtest=%random% %%2+1"
if "%rndtest%" == "1" set test=1()1
) else (
set test=1+1+1+1+1
)
set "test=1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1"
set /a "test_123_abc=%test%"
echo %test_123_abc%
```

I have tried the following solution, but to no avail :

```
@echo off & @setlocal
set "rndtest=%random% %%2+1"
if "%rndtest%" == "1" set test=1()1
) else (
set test=1+1+1+1+1
)
set /a "test_123_abc=%test%" | find "Missing operator."
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo Test failed!
) else (
echo Test didn't fail!
)
exit /b 0
```

This always evaluates to `Test didn't fail.`
It was supposed to evaluate to one of two, but it always evaluates to `Test didn't fail.`

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt window, enter `if /?`, you should find out exactly how the command works in conjunction with `else`. You appear to be using it minus the opening parenthesis! You should also check your use of doublequotes in your `set` commands, where you should always use them for safety; they're not required in your `set /a` commands

Comment: It would also assist us if you were to tell us exactly what the code is supposed/intended to do, by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58167326/edit) accordingly.

Comment: You seem to be setting the value of the variable named `test` inside your `If`/`Else` directive in your first code snippet, then immediately after, that you're setting it to a specific value `1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1`. This means that your command will always pass because that value can be evaluated properly by the subsequent `set /a "test_123_abc=%test%"` line. If you use the `Set /A` statement and receive a `Missing operator` message, that would generally be output as STDERR, so this can easily be determined, e.g. `Set /A test_123_abc=1()1 2>NUL||Echo Test failed!`

Comment: 1. You have got unbalanced parentheses, there is no opening `(` at your `if` conditions. 2. What is `set test=1()1` supposed to do? 3. Error messages are returned at _STDERR_ (handle `2`), so to be able to pipe such (`|`) you must redirect them to _STDOUT_ (handle `1`) and you must discard the original _STDOUT_ data, by `2>&1 1> nul `...

Comment: @aschipfl set test=1()1 is supposed to make set /a return an error.

Comment: I see. Change it to `set /A "1()1"`, because after having fixed the parentheses issue at `if`, the unquoted `)` will unintentionally close the block opened by `if ... (`...

Comment: @Compo Your comment really helped me. Turn it into an answer and i will upvote it and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `Set /A` statement and receive a `Missing operator` message, that would generally be output as StdErr, so this can easily be determined using the conditional operators, `&&` and `||`.

Example 1 *(redirecting just StdErr)*:

```bat
Set /A test_123_abc=1()1 2>NUL&&(Echo Test passed.)||Echo Test failed.
```

Example 2 *(redirecting both StdErr and StdOut)*:

```bat
Set /A test_123_abc=1()1 >NUL 2>&1&&(Echo Test passed.)||Echo Test failed.
```

I have redirected the StdErr to the NUL device, to prevent any error message being returned, and have use the conditionals, `&&` to represent a successful return of the previous directive and `||` to represent an unsuccessful return of the previous directive.